# Selecting procedures within a class in Fortran

Tags: class, fortran, gfortran, subroutine

How do we select procedures within classes? The compilation error is:

```
$ gfortran  -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Og -pedantic -fcheck=bounds -fbacktrace -g  -fmax-errors=5 driver.f08 
driver.f08:60:39:

         call sub ( me, myMeasurements )
                                       1
Error: More actual than formal arguments in procedure call at (1)
```

which occurs in `subroutine local_selector_sub` (line 48) within `module mIntermediates` (line 28). The argument `sub` will be either `compute_intermediates_dot` or `compute_intermediates_sum`.

The MWE code `driver.f08` tries to select a computation path. Calls to the two choices, `compute_intermediates_sum` and `compute_intermediates_dot` both work (lines 93, 94).

The problem is the call to `local_selector` (line 95) which contains the name of the target computation path. The goal is have different manifestations such as

`call myIntermediates % local_selector( compute_intermediates_sum, myMeasurements )`

or

`call myIntermediates % local_selector( compute_intermediates_dot, myMeasurements )`

MWE:

```
module mMeasurements  !   *   *   *

    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: m = 2

    type :: measurements
        real, dimension ( 1 : m ) :: x = 0.0, y = 0.0, ones = 1.0, residuals = 0.0
    contains
        private
        procedure, public :: load_data
    end type measurements

contains

    subroutine load_data ( me )

        class ( measurements ), target :: me

            me % x ( 1 ) = 1.0 !           load data
            me % x ( 2 ) = 2.0
            me % y ( 1 ) = 15.6
            me % y ( 2 ) = 17.5

    end subroutine load_data

end module mMeasurements

module mIntermediatesDefinitions  !   *   *   *

    use mMeasurements
    implicit none

    type :: intermediates
        real :: sxy = 0.0
    contains
        private
        procedure, public :: compute_intermediates_dot => compute_intermediates_dot_sub
        procedure, public :: compute_intermediates_sum => compute_intermediates_sum_sub
        procedure, public :: local_selector            => local_selector_sub
    end type intermediates

    private :: local_selector_sub
    private :: compute_intermediates_dot_sub
    private :: compute_intermediates_sum_sub

contains

    subroutine local_selector_sub ( me, sub, myMeasurements )  ! problematic routine

        class ( intermediates ), target      :: me
        type ( measurements ), intent ( in ) :: myMeasurements

        interface mySub
            subroutine sub
                use mMeasurements
                import intermediates
            end subroutine sub
        end interface mySub

        call sub ( me, myMeasurements )

    end subroutine local_selector_sub

    subroutine compute_intermediates_dot_sub ( me, myMeasurements )

        class ( intermediates ), target      :: me
        type ( measurements ), intent ( in ) :: myMeasurements

            me % sxy = dot_product ( myMeasurements % x,    myMeasurements % y )

    end subroutine compute_intermediates_dot_sub

    subroutine compute_intermediates_sum_sub ( me, myMeasurements )

        class ( intermediates ), target      :: me
        type ( measurements ), intent ( in ) :: myMeasurements

            me % sxy = sum ( myMeasurements % x * myMeasurements % y )

    end subroutine compute_intermediates_sum_sub

end module mIntermediatesDefinitions

program driver  !   #   #   #

    use mMeasurements
    use mIntermediatesDefinitions

    implicit none
    type ( measurements )  :: myMeasurements
    type ( intermediates ) :: myIntermediates

        call myIntermediates % compute_intermediates_dot ( myMeasurements )
        call myIntermediates % compute_intermediates_sum ( myMeasurements )
        call myIntermediates % local_selector            ( compute_intermediates_dot, myMeasurements )

end program driver
```

Version:
    `GNU Fortran (GCC) 5.1.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dummy procedure `sub` in subroutine `local_selector_sub` has interface given by the interface block.  That interface

```
interface
  subroutine sub
  end subroutine sub
end interface
```

(with the redundant `use` and `import` and the unused generic name removed) says that `sub` has no arguments.  In the following call you attempt to give it two arguments, and the compiler rightly complains about that.

To fix that you will need to specify the interface correctly (or rely on an implicit interface).  As I note that both options `compute_intermediates_dot_sub` and `compute_intermediates_sum_sub` have the same characteristics you could write, for example

```
subroutine local_selector_sub ( me, sub, myMeasurements )  ! problematic routine
  class ( intermediates ), target          :: me
  type ( measurements ), intent ( in )     :: myMeasurements
  procedure(compute_intermediates_dot_sub)    sub

  call sub ( me, myMeasurements )

end subroutine
```

(or you could create a neutrally named abstract interface or use an appropriate interface block).

But that leads to a much more interesting problem:

```
call myIntermediates%local_selector(compute_intermediates_dot, myMeasurements)
```

`compute_intermediates_dot` is not a subroutine.  It is a binding name for the type bound procedure of type `intermediates`.

The simplest solution if you wish to pass a subroutine to `myIntermediates%local_selector` is to make the subroutine `compute_intermediates_dot_sub` itself accessible/public and pass that.  But I'd be tempted to stick with choosing between the other two lines.

Alternatively, if you really wish to select a subroutine to pass to `myIntermediates%local_selector` then you could consider having procedure pointer components rather than type-bound procedures.